# check whether the correct installation is made via cmd with python

Tags: python, sh, raspbian

```
os.system('cd Desktop')
os.system('curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh')
```

as an example I'm installing docker on the system. What I want to do is to pass the error information to a variable if the docker is not installed correctly.and

```
os.system('curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && sudo python3 get-pip.py')
os.system('sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev python3-dev')
```

If there is not an error in the variable I want to be able to continue with these operations. Is there any library I can use about this? Thank you

Comment: use module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) - it has methods which can assign to variable text  displayed by executed comand or error code returned by this command and you can check it. ie. `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.check_all()`, `subprocess.check_output()` or even `subprocess.run()`

Comment: thank you. I look subprocess

Comment: yes this library looks nice. but there is something I can't find. How do I clone a git library that is private with subprocess?

Comment: if you need run it interactivly - ie. to send password - then you can use `stdin` in `subprocess.run()` and other functions. Or you can try module [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [invoke with watcher](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/1.2/concepts/watchers.html)

Comment: stdin didn't work for me before. but I will look again. Thank you for reviewing other modules.

Comment: see also [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)